# How to style away the thin border in Google Maps Autocomplete search bar [React Native]

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, react-native, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to create a borderless search bar from react-native-google-places-autocomplete but I can't seem to get the border or shadow or whatever it may be to disappear (image below).

Search bar rendering with border

[image: Search Bar]

This is the style code from the image. I've tried shadowOpacity: 0, translucent shadowColor, and setting a solid border with a translucent color.

```
styles = {{
            textInputContainer: {
                width: 370,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                }
```

Anyone out there successfully styled this border away? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the way they implemented the search bar, you can see what are [the default styles](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js#L26:L34):

```
textInputContainer: {
  backgroundColor: '#C9C9CE',
  height: 44,
  borderTopColor: '#7e7e7e',
  borderBottomColor: '#b5b5b5',
  borderTopWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
  borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
  flexDirection: 'row',
},
```

Then you will simply need to override them (as you tried):

```
textInputContainer: {
  borderTopWidth: 0,
  borderBottomWidth: 0,
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
 styles={{
  textInputContainer: {
   backgroundColor: "#fff0",
   borderWidth: 1,
   borderColor: Colors.snowDarkest,
   borderRadius: 3,
   padding: 0,
   justifyContent: "flex-start",
   alignItems: "flex-start",
   width: "100%",
  },
  textInput: {
   color: "#000",
   padding: 0,
   margin: 0,
  },
 }}
/>
```

If you are talking about background color then you can use this code. I am not sure which border you are pointing towards anyway hope this helps you out